# I want to scrape last price from nseindia but getting "--" this

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
**import requests**
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}
url ="https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp? 
symbol=SBIN&illiquid=0&smeFlag=0&itpFlag=0"
response = requests.get(url,headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text,'lxml')
price = soup.find_all('ul',{'class':'stock'})[0].find('span').text
print(price)

--
```

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oSzfO.png**strong text**

Comment: User API instead of parsing something from website.

Comment: hey i have a question how to get that dynamic json link from website that is shown in answer.!

Answer (score 0):

This one has interesting approach for API. There seems to be library which fetch data from NSE India.

https://nsepy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/